# How to set NSTableView background color to clear in xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I don't see a clear option when setting  the background color for a tableview in Xcode. Can I only do this in code?

I don't seem to have a "clear color" option

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of XCode are you using? And for this screenshot, what is the heading of the collapsible section of the Attributes inspector just above it? I'm wondering if you have a different Class of control selected than you're asking about... for a stock TableView I am used to seeing a very different set of choices. In any case you can always pick "Other", go to the sliders tab of the Color Picker, and set the Opacity slider at bottom to 0. That will do it.

Comment: I had the Table View selected and clicked on Background. I just say the opacity slider in custom colors and thought that might work. I'll give it a shot. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Set the background color of the table view to be RGB of Hex #000000 with Opacity being 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In interface builder select the scroll view (which contains your table view) and then uncheck `Draw Background`.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

There is the option to put a clear background in interface builder.

1. Select the table view itself.
2. Select the Attributes Inspector.
3. Scroll down to "view".
4. Select "Clear Color" in the Background choices.

Comment: I don't seem to have that option

Comment: The set of colors available is dictated by the Class of the selected object. There is a "clear color" choice on UITableView objects (iOS) but he is looking at an NSTableView (Mac).